# htaccess 301 redirect to rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am changing my site URLs with .htaccess.

Until now, I was using

`RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)/p([0-9]+)/?$ folder/handler.php?name=$1&p=$2 [L]`

Now, I want to change the "/p" for "-p".

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]+)/p([0-9]+)/?$ ^folder/([^/.]+)-p([0-9]+)/?$ [L, R=301]
```

But it gives me a 500 error when I try to access any of the two urls.

Is there any way to make a 301 from the first to the second one? Or any other choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. You have space before `R=301`
2. On RHS (target side) of `RewriteRule` you have a regex

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(folder/[^/.]+)/(p[0-9]+/?)$ /$1-$2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^folder/([^.-]+)-p([0-9]+)/?$ folder/handler.php?name=$1&p=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I cannot understand your answer.

What does the first rule do?
How will this both rules transform "folder/product-name/pXXX" into "folder/product-name-pXXXX" ?

Regards

Comment: Did you test them in your htaccess? If it works I will add explanation in my answer.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much. Now, I am trying to do the same for urls with 2 params instead of "p", I am using "c" and "v" but it doesn't work. Is possible to use as many mappings using this solution of yours or can be only one?

Comment: You should be able to extend this regex for that also. If you tell me the URL you are trying to redirect then I can suggest you something.

Comment: Is the same one but with c and v instead of p. I mean: "folder/name-whatever-i-write/vXX/cYY" to be "folder/name-whatever-i-write-vXX-cYY". But I cannot make it working. It translates it for me as "folder/name-i-write-vXX/cYY-"

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule ^(folder/[^/.]+)/(v[^/]+)/(c[^/]+)/?)$ /$1-$2-$3 [L,NC,R=301]` sorry I am on mobile so  there may be some typos.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www*******com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.******.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ www.*******.com/ [R=301,L]

Redirect /..../p /....-p
```